# Laravel 5 adding invalid chars at end of JS

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, assets

I'm including a JS file with the following tag in my `app.blade.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/colors.js"></script>
```

Whenever that script loads in the browser, it contains a bunch of invalid characters at the end.  I've verified that these characters are not present in the actual file.

Has anyone seen this problem?  Do you know a workaround?

The characters don't copy successfully to this text box, they appear to have no width when copied here...

[image]

Comment: So the invalid characters are being processed by javascript and as a result throwing some error? Could you share the error and the characters?

Comment: I'm having trouble copying the characters, but I've pasted an image of the Chrome console above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Check out this link here: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1414/bug-asset-files-incomplete-on-join-or-get-characters-appended-at looks like someone else ran into a similar issue in nginx - are you using nginx perhaps on homestead?

Comment: Yeah, I am using nginx.  Thanks!  If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an nginx issue that can be fixed by changing `sendfile on;` to `sendfile off;` in your nginx config file: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` then restarting your server.

Answer courtesy of these links:

https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1414/bug-asset-files-incomplete-on-join-or-get-characters-appended-at

https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/